# How to make data points visible in a line chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm using ASP.NET chart control, and my chart looks like this:

[image]

I would like to have a chart with data points represented, like this:
[image]

Can someone please tell me how to achieve this? Thanks..

Edit: the IsValueShownAsLabel shows the y-axis values, but doesn't "represent" different series (in my example: square and diamond). Do I need to use another property to get this done?

Comment: Could you give us a bit of your code ?

Comment: @Minh If any of the answers helped you - please mark it as accepted answer for the benefit of other users who might encounter the same problem

Comment: @Nissim: I will. It's just that my issue is only half solved :). Any idea on how to get the diamond and square representation?

Comment: @Minh Try: `Chart.Series[0].SmartLabelStyle = new SmartLabelStyle { CalloutLineAnchorCapStyle = LineAnchorCapStyle.Diamond };`

Comment: That doesn't have any effects on the graph

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Chart.Series[0].MarkerSize` and `Chart.Series[0].MarkerStyle`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Microsoft's data visualization asp.net charts, simple use the following:
`Chart.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel=true;`

More: [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/suthish_nair/mschart-how-to-draw-a-line-or-multiple-line-chart/)

Answer (score 2):

To show the values of the points as label you should set the property `IsValueShownAsLabel` to `true`.